# how to import a dll into a asp.net web application running on webserver

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I have a dll created in VS 2010. i put it into the app_code folder on the webserver
and then i accesses it by trying to use `imports GetWebPageData`

the dll is in the vs project under bin/debug if that means anything

Comment: Right click on the project in VS2010 and select Add reference and browse to the dll and add it.

Comment: I am trying to add the dll to a web application which is running on the server, it was not created in VS2010. only the dll was created in 2010

Comment: There is no vs running on server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to copy the DLL to the `bin` (instead of `app_code`) folder of the web server, and even better - click on Add Reference on the Web Site in Visual Studio and add your DLL as a reference.
And you should also probably read some more about ASP.NET fundamentals

Here is an article that explains ASP.NET compilation in detail:
http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/AspNetCompilation/AspNetCompilation.asp

Comment: the website is running on server and not in vs

Comment: i get error - This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: then you need to build your assembly (the DLL file) with the same version of the .NET framework. Check what version are you running on the server - that's done with the IIS console, check the properties of the web application.
Then, in Visual Sudio go to project properties of your class library and set the same version explicitly.