# .dll files successfully added but are not enabled in the active designer

Tags: asp.net

When I use .dll files in the ASP.net toolbox with the chosen item menu, a message displays like: "The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer". I want to use this .dll (Aguage.dll file downloaded from internet & want to use in my project).
What can I do to solve this issue.

This .dll file basically contain a gauge like speed meter of car, clock etc

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The following link appears to have the answer to your question (though is slightly different, it appears).

[how to import a dll into a asp.net web application running on webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598843/how-to-import-a-dll-into-a-asp-net-web-application-running-on-webserver)

So hopefully you should find all the info you need there. However if you need more help do let me know :).

Edit: I have checked and the initial version of the file seems to have been created for .NET 2.0 rather than the version you are currently using. There may be a way to amend the DLL file but I would suggest this is problem.

Edit 2: Works fine on my system with latest version of VSEE 2015 so outdated file doesn't seem to be the issue. Suggest there is a likely a probably with user's setup. More info in comments.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17559/A-fast-and-performing-gauge

I have uploaded a video to help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWFIgFonZ3A

(in reply to the user who previously removed reference to this question, this is not a link only answer *by any stretch of the imagination*; furthermore, the answer holds information which is likely useful to other users and is part of a process of ongoing inquiry into the roots of the user's issues, which we are more than happy to look into as deeply as the concerned party is willing to furnish us with additional information)

Additional note: At the current time our best information has been forthcoming regarding the problem the user is experiencing. If the user wishes additional support, and assuming Visual Studio had been installed from scratch, we would be ok to remote on to the user's system if they wish us to do so